# Find the size of maze corridors in a image

Tags: java

So I am building a application to solve mazes one of the options is upload a picture and it will solve it. However upon solving the maze the output will look like this.

[image: maze]

I would like to figure out how to make my program find the proper corridor size and have the solution look like this with the pathway completely full

[image]

My data is put into a array with 1's representing the walls and 0's the spaces like [this](https://pastebin.com/UWG8Wyzm). So far I have thought about trying to find the smallest distance between 1's but that runs into problems with circular mazes and writing on the maze. I have thought about filling the distance between the walls but that runs into problems at intersections.

I am drawing on the image using

```
image.setRGB(x, y, Color.RED.getRGB());
```

with the image being a BufferedImage.

I am truly all out of ideas and don't know how to come at this problem any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `the output will look like this.` - so you already know how to solve the maze?  `My data is put into a array with 1's representing the walls and 0's the spaces` - so each 1/0 represents a cell in the image. So you could keep an ArrayList of Points to represent each cell to be included in the solution. Then you iterate through the ArrayList and use the fillRect(...) method to paint each cell in the ArrayList.

Comment: Why are you drawing directly into the image's buffer? Why not extract a Graphics2D object, set its Stroke and draw with that?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Because that still doesn't solve the problem of knowing how big I would need to make the stroke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each square in your grid has a certain size. Say `wsq` * `hsq` for "width of square times height of square".

Given your much more fine-grained `(x, y)`, you can find in which square it is by dividing `x` by `wsq` and `y` by `wsh`:

```
int xsq = x / wsq;
int ysq = y / ysq;
```

The area to paint red would be from `(xsq * wsq, ysq * hsq)` and have width/height `(wsq, hsq)`. and you could paint that red, but it would mean that you paint over the walls. So you have to adjust the area you're going to fill with red color by the size of the walls. If the walls are all two pixels thick, you need to add 1 to the x and the y coordinate of the square, and substract 2 from the widht and the height.

And you could fill it again (with a `Graphics2D`) for every time that you are now calling `image.setRGB` or you could remember which squares that you already filled.

Note: since you are working with regular-sized squares, you can also optimize your maze-solving algorithm to work in a grid of squares of size `(wsq, hsq)` rather than the individual pixels in the image.